# Массивы в java

Tags: массивы, java

У меня есть массив из целых чисел,который я перевела в строку методом Integer.toString.Но при выводе на экран,строка ,почему-то,сдвигается на одну позицию вперед,а на первой позиции пусто...чем это объяснить?
выглядит это так:

```
первоначальный массив:"10010100"
строка:" 10010100"
```

заранее спасибо :)

```
package javaapplication37;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 *
 * @author Evgeniya
 */
public class JavaApplication37 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int cislo= sc.nextInt();
        prevod(cislo);

        }

    public static void prevod(int cislo){
        int count=1;
        int cisloo=cislo;
        int i=0;
        while((cislo/10)>=10){
            count++; 
            cislo/=10;
    }
        count+=2;
        int[]pole=new int[count-1];
        while(cisloo>0){
            pole[i]=cisloo%10;
            cisloo/=10;
            i++;
        }

        int[]pole1=new int[pole.length];
        int len=pole.length;
        for(int h=0;h<pole.length;h++){
            pole1[h]=pole[len-1];
            len--;
        }
        String str=toString(pole);
        System.out.println(str);
      int count2=str.length()-1;

    for(int f=count2;f>=3;f=f-3){
          if((str.substring(f-2,f+1)).equals("001")){
           System.out.print(1);

          }  
     }
         if((pole.length%3)==1){
                 System.out.print(1);
               }
          if((pole.length%3)==2){
              if((str.substring(0,2)).equals("10")){
                  System.out.print(3);
              }
              if((str.substring(0,2)).equals("11")){
                  System.out.print(4);
              }
          }

    }

    public static String toString(int[]pole){
            String vozik=" ";
            String str=new String();
        for(int u=0;u<pole.length;u++){
                vozik+=Integer.toString(pole[u]);
}
        return vozik;

}
}
```

P.S. не судите строго,я только на первом курсе :)
Хотела сделать калькулятор перевода из двоичной системы в восьмиричную. Пока что поставила одно пробное значение 001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не судя строго: вы сами добавляете пробел в начало строки. См. определение переменной `vozik`.

Answer (score 1):

> Хотела сделать калькулятор перевода из
> двоичной системы в восьмиричную.

Я не хочу никого критиковать, но зачем так усложнять. 
Вот вся программа:

```
  String number = "0010110"; //строка с Вашим бинарным числом
   System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(Integer.parseInt(number,2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая, что каждое восьмиричное число состоит из 3х двуичных чисел, то можно массив по 3 элемента обрабатывать, я так сделал:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TwoToEightBit {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    System.out.println("8-bit number is : " + converter(input));
}

private static StringBuilder converter(String input) {
    int k = 0;
    int number = 0;
    StringBuilder number8 = new StringBuilder();

    if (input.length() < 3) {
        input = "00" + input;
    }

    char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("2-bit number is : " + input);

    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        number += Character.getNumericValue(arr[i]) * Math.pow(2, k++);
        if (k > 2) {
            number8.append(number);
            number = 0;
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    if (number > 0) {
        return number8.append(number).reverse();
    }
    return number8.reverse();
}
```

Тоже не судите строго, учусь :)

}